# I want to know how can I access images from next frontend public folder

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose, next.js

[image]

Here is my folder structure. I store all photos in frontend public folder (next.js). I want to know how can I send email from backend and still got the access to images from frontend public folder. I tried it using absolute paths and when I tested it on Mailtrap it doesn't work. I use nodemailer for sending email btw.

The result that I get:
[image]

Comment: If you want to use an image in an email you need to reference the image by http link you cant just send the image itself in the email. So if you know the name of the image then you can just link to it `<image src="http://yoursite.com/images/image.jpg">` in your html email template. You don't really need access to the folder to do this.

Comment: How can I use my website url to test in development?

Comment: I usually just make the html templates by themselves separate from your project like you would any html template. If you want to test emails with nodemailer then you can use dummy images from placeholder.com or just upload your images to your server.

Answer (score 1):

Try placing them in frontent/public/images/`yourImageName` and using it in code like this:

```
<img src="/images/yourImageName" />
```